# Remove following duplicate values from dict of DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, duplicates

I have a dict with DataFrame as value.

It looks like this:

```
print(fetched)
'2021-04-27':   column1 column2 colum3 ...
0   334 213 312 ...
1   222 222 707 ...
...

'2021-04-28':   column1 column2 colum3 ...
0   334 213 312 ...
1   222 222 707 ...
...

'2021-04-29':   column1 column2 colum3 ...
0   334 213 312 ...
1   222 222 707 ...
...

'2021-04-30':   column1 column2 colum3 ...
0   334 213 312 ...
1   292 242 707 ...
...

'2021-05-01':   column1 column2 colum3 ...
0   334 213 312 ...
1   232 222 787 ...
...

'2021-05-02':   column1 column2 colum3 ...
0   334 213 312 ...
1   232 222 787 ...
...

'2021-05-03':   column1 column2 colum3 ...
0   334 213 872 ...
1   232 232 787 ...
...

print(type(fetched))
<class 'dict'>

print(type(fetched["2021-04-27"]))
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

print(type(fetched["2021-04-30"].column1))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

I want to remove following keys from this dict with duplicate values.
(Duplicate value: exactly the same DataFrame)
The output should look like this:

```
print(fetched_cleaned)
'2021-04-27':   column1 column2 colum3 ...
0   334 213 312 ...
1   222 222 707 ...
...

'2021-04-30':   column1 column2 colum3 ...
0   334 213 312 ...
1   222 222 707 ...
...

'2021-05-01':   column1 column2 colum3 ...
0   334 213 312 ...
1   232 222 787 ...
...

'2021-05-03':   column1 column2 colum3 ...
0   334 213 872 ...
1   232 232 787 ...
...
```

I tried it really simple like this but it returns a list and values are still duplicate:

```
fetched_cleaned = []
for x in fetched:
    if x not in fetched_cleaned:
        fetched_cleaned.append(x)
```

Surely the solution is pretty simple but I don't get it. I don't now how to handle this DataFrame object. I also tried solutions with set and sort/group by but there is always this AttributeError ...
Maybe someone more experienced than me with DataFrames can help me with this.

Comment: How are you defining duplicate?

Comment: When the following df is exactly the same.

Comment: The data in the following df matches the previous? and you're only comparing pairwise two dfs? Not unique contents in the whole set? Did you split these dataframes into a dict of dataframes before this? Because this operation would be easier with a single df

Comment: Not unique content in the df. Df is only duplicate if the whole df matches the previous.

Comment: can you filter before hand ? Like do not load dataframes coming from the same file name?

Comment: You can have a look at `df.equals(df2)` https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting your dict into a DataFrame with the csv representation in one column and the key as the index. Then use Boolean Indexing to compare the rows. Then convert back to a dict or dataframes.

```py
from io import StringIO

import pandas as pd

d = {
    "A": pd.DataFrame({0: [1, 2]}),
    "B": pd.DataFrame({0: [4, 5]}),
    "C": pd.DataFrame({0: [1, 2]}),
    "D": pd.DataFrame({0: [1, 2]}),
    "E": pd.DataFrame({0: [6, 7]}),
}

# Convert To DataFrame Of csvs
new_df = pd.DataFrame({0: {k: v.to_csv() for k, v in d.items()}})
# Compare Every Two Rows and turn back into DataFrames
new_df = new_df[new_df[0].ne(new_df[0].shift())][0] \
    .apply(lambda s: pd.read_csv(StringIO(s), index_col=0))
# Convert Back To Dict
new_dict = new_df.to_dict()

for item in new_dict.items():
    print(item[0])
    print(item[1])
    print(type(item[1]))
```

```
A
   0
0  1
1  2
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
B
   0
0  4
1  5
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
C
   0
0  1
1  2
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
E
   0
0  6
1  7
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Comment: Great, thank you. This should work. I need to check my dfs because new_dict has same keys as d for me ...

Comment: Yes it works as expected. `print(new_df["2021-04-27"].column1) == print(fetched["2021-04-28"].column1)`

Comment: new_df is correctly filled with values but not filtered.

Comment: Yes, of couse. Would be great if you can help me. It has many columns so I think I need to upload it. You can look at line 86 in read_fetched.py. https://wetransfer.com/downloads/6a7916c8227abb89ac51bc2cf8a267ed20210503160804/861e90

Comment: I've updated to use csv instead of dict. try now.

Answer (score 0):

checking for all overlaps (code not tested)

```
fetched_cleaned = []
list_fetched = list(fetched.values())
for i, x in enumerate(list_fetched):
    duplicated = False
    for j in range(0, i):
        if x.equals(list_fetched[j]):
            duplicated = True
            break
    if duplicated == False:
        fetched_cleaned.append(x)
```

If this "Df is only duplicate if the whole df matches the previous" is true then:

```
fetched_cleaned = []
list_fetched = list(fetched.values())
for i, x in enumerate(list_fetched):
    if not x.equals(list_fetched[i-1]):
        fetched_cleaned.append(x)
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! I don't know why but I cannot use equals(). I get a TypeError: 'dict_values' object is not subscriptable.

Comment: you used `list_fetched = fetched.values()` ? the error says that we are using the [i-1] on a dictionary instead of a list

Comment: Yes:
`list_fetched = fetched.values()
print(type(list_fetched))
<class 'dict_values'>`

Comment: then add a `list()` : `list_fetched = list(fetched.values())`